# Closed form for zeros.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $t \in [0,1]$ and $f(x) = (x+t)e^{1/(1+x^2)}-\frac{3}{2}t -x$. Is it true that this function has exactly one root on $[0,\infty)$ and is there a closed form for it in terms of $t$? I'm not quite sure how to show that this is true or false, and in particular finding the formula. If there does not exist a formula for the root, is it true that as $t \to 0$, the roots diverge? Is there any hint or suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit skeptical about a closed form for the root. There is a simple formula for $t$
$$t(x)=\frac{2 \left(e^{\frac{1}{x^2+1}}-1\right) x}{3-2 e^{\frac{1}{x^2+1}}}$$ but its inversion does not seem possible even using special functions.

If we consider the problem for small values of $t$ (that is to say for large values of $x$), by Taylor we have
$$t=\frac{2}{x}+\frac{3}{x^3}+\frac{13}{3 x^5}+\frac{77}{12 x^7}+\frac{187}{20
   x^9}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^{11}}\right)$$ and using series reversion
$$x=\frac{2}{t}+\frac{3 t}{4}-\frac{7 t^3}{24}+\frac{11 t^5}{48}-\frac{163
   t^7}{720}+O\left(t^9\right)$$ Trying for $t=\frac 1 {1000}$, this truncated series gives
$$x=\frac{1440000539999790000164999837}{720000000000000000000000}$$  which is $$x\approx 2000.00074999970833356249977361111$$ while the "exact" solution is    $$x=2000.00074999970833356249977361136$$

For $t=\frac 12$, the approximation gives
$$x=\frac{400337}{92160}\approx 4.34393$$ while the exact solution is $x=4.344314$.

**Edit**

There is another way to get more and more accurate closed form approximations when $x$ is large.

Let $x=\frac 1y$ and consider the function $f(y)=0$. Now, build the $[1,n]$ Padé approximant of it built around $y=0$. It will write
$$f(y) \sim \frac {a^{(m)}y -t } {1+\sum_{i=1}^m b_i^{(m)} y)^i}\implies y=\frac t {a^{(m)}} \implies x=\frac  {a^{(m)}} t$$ All coefficients $a^{(m)}$ and $b_i^{(m)}$ are defined by the values of function and its derivatives at $y=0$.

For the fun of it, I give you the one for $m=9$. It write
$$x_{(9)}=\frac{2 \left(8521 t^8+94080 t^6+269280 t^4+276480 t^2+92160\right)}{3t
   \left(561 t^8+15600 t^6+64000 t^4+80640 t^2+30720 \right)}$$

For $t=\frac 1 {1000}$ it gives a relative error of $7.73 \times 10^{-33}$%.

Comment: How did you find the expansion of $t$ with negative powers of $x$?

Comment: @Raffaele Make $x=\frac 1y$, expand around $y=0$ and go back to $x$ using long division.